# jQuery UI Date Picker Ajax Click Event

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using jQuery ui datepicker that displays a list of checkboxes for different appointment times onselect through an ajax request.  The problem I am having is that when I click on a date the list of times is populated but the click event on the checkbox is not firing. Not sure how to use .on('click', function()[]); with jQuery ui datepicker.

Below is the code for the ajax request.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
    onSelect: function(date) {
        $.ajax
        ({
              type: 'POST',
              url: '/member-area/ajax-apt/get-availability',
              data: 'date='+date,
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function(json)
              {
                if (json.status == "success")
                {             
                    var start = json.hours['0']['open'];
                    var end = json.hours['0']['close'];

                    var endDate = new Date(Date.parse(json.date+' '+end));
                    var currentDate = new Date(Date.parse(json.date+' '+start));
                    var availability = [];
                    var html = '<div id="avail-hours"><p>Your Appointment day is on </br><div class="date bg-primary">' + date + '<span id="time"></span></div><h4>Now select the time of your fitness appointment</h4>';


                    while(currentDate < endDate) {
                        var increment = currentDate.setMinutes(currentDate.getMinutes() + 30);

                        currentDate = new Date(increment);
                        html += '<form class="form-inline"><label class="checkbox col-sm-5"><input type="checkbox" name="stime" value="' + formatAMPM(currentDate) + '"> '+ formatAMPM(currentDate) + '</label>';
                    }

                    function formatAMPM(date) {
                      var hours = date.getHours();
                      var minutes = date.getMinutes();
                      var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
                      hours = hours % 12;
                      hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
                      minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
                      var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
                      return strTime;
                    }

                    html += '</form></div>';
                    $('#avail-hours').replaceWith(html);
                    $('#next').removeClass('hidden');

                    var input_select = $("input[name='stime']:checked")
                    var cnt = input_select.length;

                    if (cnt == 0) 
                    {
                        $('#next').attr('disabled', true);
                    } 
                }
                else
                { 
                  $('p.feedback').addClass('alert alert-error').html(json.message).fadeIn(400, function () {$("p.feedback").delay(5000).fadeOut(400);});
                }
              }
         });  
    },
    minDate:0, 
    maxDate: "+2M +10D" 
});
});
```

Comment: Using .on() should work! you don't have to put it inside the ajax

Comment: @samcreamer the click event on the checkbox does not work on the first click, but only the second and any further clicks.  The list is created dynamically based on the date selected through an ajax request sent by the jquery ui datepicker.

Comment: is there some way you can set up a jsfiddle that demonstrates the issue?